# best practices - main menu with ajax and clean url's

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

There are some examples out there that implement a main menu with ajax and use the history API to get nice and expressive url's.

For example: http://diveintohtml5.info/examples/history/casey.html

The problem, following the example, is that you need 2 files per dog, one for the ajax content request, and the other for the url including a header, footer and so on - which even if its just a php include, is annoying to maintain becasue there are lots of duplicate files (especially in the case where there are more people editing the website)

Is there not a better way to do this?

Comment: .htaccess rewrite rules

Comment: u got an example somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt I am understanding you question correctly but here goes how I would handle it

```
<?
include("assign.inc");

if ($_REQUEST["hide"] != "all"){
   include("head.inc");
}
?>
page content <img src="test.jpg">
<?
if ($_REQUEST["hide"] != "all"){
   include("foot.inc");
}
?>
```

So the ajax call would simply have ?hide=all on the url (or as a post)...if you want to only show the image (and not the text) simply add more criteria (modify hide if's)

Comment: Also you shouldn't really have to create separate files per dog...if you set the dogs up in a db then you can call them dynamically via dog.php?id=1...which would pull down the appropriate txt/images etc.

Comment: thats where the .htaccess stuff comes in...translating /sample/dog/url to dog.php?id=1

Comment: i think i get it now.. though im not going to implement a database (its a small website)